# "next" undefined in beforeRouteUpdate

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, decorator, vue-router

```
@Component({
  mixins: [template],
  components: {
    Sidebar
  }
})
export default class AppContentLayout extends Vue {

  @Prop({default: 'AppContent'})
  heading: string;

  @Watch('$route')
  beforeRouteUpdate (to: Object, from: Object, next: Function) {
    // react to route changes...
    // don't forget to call next()
    Logger.log(to)
    Logger.log(from)
    next();
  }
}
```

Based on the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), `beforeRouteUpdate` should receive `to`, `from` and `next`. However, for me `next` is always undefined, whether I use the watch option from [a property decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) or when I add it to the `mixins` in  `@component`. Both work in that the hook is called, but next is always `undefined`. I thought maybe `next` is only defined if passed, but the docs state:

> Make sure to always call the next function, otherwise the hook will never be resolved.

which is why I'm assuming it is also always present. I guess if it is only present if passed, a simply

```
if(isFunction(next)) next()
```

So really what Im asking is: is `next` only available if explicitly passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the docs say

> To react to params changes in the same component, you can simply watch the $route object:

and

> Or, use the beforeRouteUpdate guard introduced in 2.2:

When you use the typescript annotations, you must name the callback you hook up to. I just happen to call it `beforeRouteUpdate` unfortunately as I also looked it up in the router docs. Now I thought it would call `beforeRouteUpdate`, which it didn't, it just called the callback I named like that.

So just renaming the callback to `onRouteChange` makes more sense and "did the trick"

Answer (score 2):

Not at all sure what the answer is referring to actually. But I ran into this same issue and for me it was b/c I was registering more hooks than I was using thinking it wouldn't matter. Once I only registered the one I had defined, it worked as expected.

I.e. if the component only provides beforeRouteUpdate, this won't work:

```
Component.registerHooks([
    'beforeRouteEnter',
    'beforeRouteLeave',
    'beforeRouteUpdate'
]);
```

but this will:

```
Component.registerHooks([
    'beforeRouteUpdate'
]);
```

Comment: I had a watch called "beforeRouteUpdate". I just fooled myself thinking it would have a next callback, but I just named a normal (watch) function beforeRouteUpdate, it was not actually a navguard

Comment: @Mark Zhukovsky wow, thanks for that, do you know why this happen actually? I also registered all hooks thinking it would not matter but apparently it does matter and it's pretty hard to find documentation for it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Vue, but I wonder if you are mixing two mechanisms here... you seem to be doing both a watch, and a before route update all relating to the same method.

Watch doesn't get the `next` argument, whereas `beforeRouteUpdate` does, so I imagine the missing argument is related to that `Watch` attribute triggering the method with just `to` and `from`.

## Watch

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

## beforeRouteUpdate

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // react to route changes...
    // don't forget to call next()
  }
}
```

Comment: when I remove the `@Watch`, `beforeRouteUpdate` is not called anymore though. edit: I think I understand the issue and you are kinda right.